# symfony file import (csv)

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to import datas to database from a csv file, but I can't do it. I've got code below. I want to print datas from csv yet, but it gives me error:

```
Warning: fopen(soubor.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/VWM/src/VWM/ProjektBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 56
```

How can I solve it?

```
public function addProductAction() {
    $product = new Product;
    $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $product);
    $form2 = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('form2name')
        ->add('submitFile', 'file', array('label' => 'CSV'))
        ->getForm();

    $m = 'nevyplněno';
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {

        // add one product, it works
        if($request->request->has('vwm_projektbundle_producttype')) {
            $form->bindRequest($request);
            if($form->isValid()) {
                return $this->forward('VWMProjektBundle:Default:result', array('product' => $product));
            } else {
                $m = 'Chybně vyplněný formulář';
            }
        }

        // add products from CSV
        if($request->request->has('form2name')) {
            $form2->bindRequest($request);
            if($form2->isValid()) {
                // Get File
                $file = $form2->get('submitFile');
                // your csv file here when you hit submit button
                $filename = $file->getData();           
                //print_r($data); // this returns filename.csv
                $row = 1;
                if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== FALSE) {
                    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100, ";")) !== FALSE) {
                        $num = count($data);
                        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
                        $row++;
                        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
                      }
                    }
                    fclose($handle);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'form2' => $form2->createView(),
        'm' => $m,
        );
}
```

Comment: You've answered your own question. The file does not exist (you need to correct the path). The warning makes that clear.

Comment: So what's wrong with my code? :-(

Comment: You are opening a file **without** path

Comment: The error message tells you everything you need to know. There is "No such file or directory" Look at line 56 in /var/www/VWM/src/VWM/ProjektBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

Answer (score 1):

Replace these lines:

```
$filename = $file->getData();           
//print_r($data); // this returns filename.csv
```

With:

```
$filename = $file->getData();           
print_r($data); // this returns filename.csv
die(' <-- actual path');
```

Is the path you see the correct one to your file?

To test your code you can simply put the absolute path in the **$filename** var first. If it doesn't work with the correct absolute path, check the rights on the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$csvFile = $form->get('csvFile')->getData()->getPathName();
```

It will return your complete temp file pathname.